# What's the GTK header I need to include so I can use lookup_widget?

Tags: c, gtk, header-files

As shown in the example below, this callback function is when the user clicks an OK button. I can get window (the top level widget) from button by using gtk_widget_get_toplevel, but I'm stuck trying to get a widget pointer for a GtkEntry widget with name ENTRY.

```
/* Called when OK button is clicked */
on_BT_OK_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    //The line directly below is the one I get an error on
    GtkWidget *entry = lookup_widget( GTK_WIDGET(button), "ENTRY" );

    gchar *text1, *text2;
    text1 = gtk_entry_get_text( GTK_ENTRY(entry));
    text2 = g_strconcat("Hello, ", text1, NULL);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_widget_get_toplevel (GTK_WIDGET(button));
    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new( window,
                                               GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
                                               GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
                                               GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
                                               text2);
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

But I get the error "undefined reference to lookup_widget." I can find a billion examples of snippets of code using lookup_widget, but not a single one full source code example showing the headers that enable the use of it. I'm using Anjuta3.2.0 and the latest Glade plugin.

Comment: `lookup_widget` cannot be a public function from GTK. They all have `gtk` as prefix.

Comment: OK, so I formed my question wrong. lookup_widget is a Glade utility function. Does anyone know the right header to include so I can use this *Glade* utility function?

Comment: `lookup_widget` seems to be a function *generated* by Glade; did you searched it in your generated files? http://www.fifi.org/doc/glade-common/help/glade/C/faq/index.html

Comment: As seen in the link section 1.4.5 make use of glade APIs. @BasileStarynkevitch: Maybe you should post that as an answer with the suggested alternative mentioned in your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Basile Starynkevitch says, `lookup_widget()` was a function generated by Glade 2. However, code generation by Glade has been deprecated for quite a long time now, in favor of (first) libglade and (later) GtkBuilder. In fact, Glade 3 won't even do it.

The preferred solution is to pass a pointer to your ENTRY as the user data pointer when you connect the signal, or, if you're using `gtk_builder_connect_signals()`, store a pointer to ENTRY in your class and pass the class as the user data pointer.

However, if you *must* use `lookup_widget()`, here's the source that Glade 2 generated as of about 6 years ago:

```
GtkWidget*
lookup_widget (GtkWidget *widget,
               const gchar *widget_name)
{
  GtkWidget *parent, *found_widget;

  for (;;)
    {
      if (GTK_IS_MENU (widget))
        parent = gtk_menu_get_attach_widget (GTK_MENU (widget));
      else
        parent = widget->parent;
      if (!parent)
        parent = (GtkWidget*) g_object_get_data (G_OBJECT (widget), "GladeParentKey");
      if (parent == NULL)
        break;
      widget = parent;
    }

  found_widget = (GtkWidget*) g_object_get_data (G_OBJECT (widget),
                                                 widget_name);
  if (!found_widget)
    g_warning ("Widget not found: %s", widget_name);
  return found_widget;
}
```

For this to work, you have to do the following for *every* widget contained within a toplevel window:

```
g_object_set_data_full (G_OBJECT (toplevel), "name-of-widget", gtk_widget_ref (widget), (GDestroyNotify) gtk_widget_unref);
```

and then the following once for each toplevel window:

```
g_object_set_data (G_OBJECT (toplevel), "name-of-toplevel", toplevel);
```

Seems to me to be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Glade-2 implements `lookup_widget()` in `support.c` and the header is `support.h`
Once the GLADE GUI is converted to C codes these files are generated automatically.